# How do I get the UserVoice Feedback Tab to display on a Facebook app page using FBML?

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs, uservoice

I have a Facebook application that is using FBML and I want to include the [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com) feedback tab widget on my app's pages. I copied and pasted the JavaScript into my FBML page, but when Facebook renders the page, that JavaScript is removed, so the tab doesn't show up.

Does anyone have experience with [Facebook's modified version of JavaScript](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS) and getting the UserVoice tab to work on a FBML page?

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
<script>
<!--
  var uservoiceJsHost = ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://uservoice.com" : "http://cdn.uservoice.com";
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + uservoiceJsHost + "/javascripts/widgets/tab.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"))
//-->
</script>
<script>
<!--
UserVoice.Tab.show({ 
  /* required */
  key: 'callme',
  host: 'callme.uservoice.com', 
  forum: '31286', 
  /* optional */
  alignment: 'left',
  background_color:'#f00', 
  text_color: 'white',
  hover_color: '#06C',
  lang: 'en'
})
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about JavaScript. Just include the following HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
#uservoice-dialog
{
    display: block;
    margin: -2em auto 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100003;
}
#uservoice-overlay
{
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100002;
}
#uservoice-dialog[id], #uservoice-overlay[id]
{
    position: fixed;
}
#uservoice-overlay p
{
    color: #ddd;
    font: bold 14px arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
#uservoice-dialog #uservoice-dialog-close
{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #06c;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: -11px;
    width: 48px;
}
* html.dialog-open body
{
    height: 100%;
}
* html.dialog-open, * html.dialog-open body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
html.dialog-open object, html.dialog-open embed, * html.dialog-open select
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
* html #uservoice-overlay
{
    width: 110%;
}
* html #uservoice-dialog #uservoice-dialog-close
{
    background: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='https://uservoice.com/images/icons/close.png');
}
a#uservoice-dialog-close
{
    background-image: url(http://cdn.uservoice.com/images/icons/close.png);
}
</style>
<a href="YOUR_USERVOICE_PAGE_URL_HERE" id="uservoice-feedback-tab">Feedback</a>
```

That should put a UserVoice tab up on your page. You can customize the CSS as much as you like.

Note that this skips the UserVoice modal dialog (which wouldn't work very well on Facebook anyways) and takes users directly to your UserVoice homepage.

Comment: Looking at this in more detail now, you've got a bunch of css classes, but how/where are you proposing to use those?

Comment: The only thing the UserVoice JavaScript does is add those classes and a couple of elements to your page. The CSS is actually more than you need; if you wanted to you could just pick out the "uservoice-feedback-tab" style.

Answer (score 2):

You could also sign up for the new UserVoice Facebook tab that allows you to embed UserVoice directly into your Facebook pages. That would probably be the best solution! (Full disclosure, I am the co-founder at UserVoice)

www.uservoice.com/facebook

Comment: This goes into Facebook pages, but what about UV for Facebook apps?